# Linux IO redirection with colors

Tags: linux, bash

There are some commands in Linux that have options to keep colors regardless of the IO redirection, for example:

```
| grep --color=always
```

Is there way to keep colors for output redirection for any custom program?

In my particular example, I use cmake with color output which is redirected to sed to highlight warnings and errors (using http://shawnwilsher.com/2008/12/highlight-warnings-in-make/).

Comment: I presume you meant `| grep --color=always` (pipe instead of redirect to file).

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10823/where-do-my-ansi-escape-codes-go-when-i-pipe-to-another-process-can-i-keep-them/10832#10832

Answer (score 0):

Programs decide to turn coloring sequences off by checking if file descriptor 1 points to /dev/stdout. If there is no option to override that check, you have to 'be the terminal' for the program.

I found [InterceptTTY](http://www.suspectclass.com/sgifford/interceptty/) which is supposed to do exactly that, although i have no experience with it.